# Notifications For User Having Opened Another Application?

Tags: ios, swift

My iOS application (using Swift) needs to react to a user having opened another application.  It does not necessarily need to know what app it is. It just needs to know that the app being opened is not the phone call/dialer app, because the dialer app would be the only app that receives an exception from my application. I do not want to stop the user from opening the other apps, but just have my app react to that action.

I know it is possible, because there is an app on the app store that uses this functionality currently.  The app I am referring to is called Forest- Stay Focused. It seems like I should be able to use the AppDelegate functions somehow, but I cannot seem to figure out how.

How can I accomplish what I am looking to do?

Comment: You can use `didEnterBackground` and/or `willResignActive` app delegate functions/notifications to detect the user moving out of your app.  [`CXCallObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallobserver) can provide an indication of an incoming call as long as your app is in the foreground.

Comment: @Paulw11 didEnterBackground and willResignActive could happen even when the user turns off the phone/phone screen though right? I dont want the application to react to the user doing those things if they are not accessing another application.

Comment: Those are the only functions you have to work with.